# Validation on read-only field in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-8

I have a field that produces the a calculation of 2 other fields and give an output which is stored in my database. I need this field to always be positive(my calculation is 480-input1+input2) so if a user puts 480 for input1 and 300 for input2, I get a negative value. I managed to show a message if the field was a negative value but after making the field a `readonly` field, it does not give me the error and stores the negative value.

My View:

```
<div class="mb-3" style="float:left;" style="margin-left: 200px;">
  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Admin time (minutes):</label>
  <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="admin_time"   class="form-control" id="admin_time" min="1" step="1" readonly required>
</div>
<div class="mb-3" >
  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Work time (minutes):</label>
  <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="work_time"  class="form-control" id="work_time" onchange="myChangeFunction(this)" min="1" max="480" step="1"  required >
</div>
<div >
  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Driving time (minutes):</label>
  <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="driving_time"  class="form-control" id="driving_time" onchange="myChangeFunction(this)" min="'480'-document.getElementById('work_time').value" max="480"   required>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
  $request->validate([
            'admin_time'=>'required|min:0|max:480',
        ]);
```

Comment: What do you mean as 'readonly' field. What field you make readonly and does it mean that you add readonly attribute to that field?

Comment: @silentwasd I have updated the code. `admin_time` is my read only field

Comment: First of all you need to use not 'min' and 'max' rules in your controller validation. You need to use 'gte' (great than or equal) and 'lte' (less than or equal) respectively.

Comment: @silentwasd I believe lte and gte dont allow for integers but fields, yes?

Comment: Sorry for that. My bad

Comment: @silentwasd do you think there is another way?

Comment: what about your "negative manage" function? Maybe you put it code to description.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: Your validation negative code written on javascript?

Comment: I dont have any validation code for negative

Comment: Why you use readonly? For disable input?

Comment: disable input wont store in my database right?

Comment: Yes. Try to use disabled attribute instead of readonly.

Comment: I tried it, and it does not stroe the record which is good but there should be an error message that shows instead of allowing submission